# filter a list inside a class in .net

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I have this class models :

```
public record AllTransactionsResponse
    {
        public List<TransactionItem> Item { get; init; }
    }
    public record TransactionItem
    {
        public string FundCode { get; init; }
        public FundTransactionResponse IssuanceItem { get; init; }
        public FundRedemptionTransactionResponse RedemptionItem { get; init; }
    }
```

I want to filter some records with FundCode :

```
        var allTransactions = new AllTransactionsResponse();

        allTransactions = allTransactions.Item.Where(i => i.FundCode!="11277").ToList();
```

But I get convert error ,I know what is the problem and I should convert the value to target model,But I need the fastest way to do this :

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<easy.fund.api.Application.Queries.TransactionItem>' to 'easy.fund.api.Application.Queries.AllTransactionsResponse
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues here.

If you look at this code

```
allTransactions.Item.Where(i => i.FundCode != "11277").ToList();
```

you will see that it returns an `IEnumerable<TransactionItem>` which you then convert into a `List<>`

But you expect a type of `AllTransactionsResponse`.  So you need to assign it to your Item property within this class

```
allTransactions.Item = allTransactions.Item.Where(i => i.FundCode != "11277").ToList();
```

But then you will have another problem.  You have declared this property as

```
public List<TransactionItem> Item { get; init; }
```

So you can't assign it later.

So then you need to either change this to be of type `{ get; set; }` or use some other method to do this.

As you are assigning the result back to the original item, then you could simply remove then using `RemoveAll`

```
int numberRemoved = allTransactions.Item.RemoveAll(delegate (TransactionItem item) { return item.FundCode.Equals("11277"); });
```

This way you don't need to change your property declaration and it is clearer what you are actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `RemoveAll` method to get the items other then not having `FundCode`  as 11277. like this`allTransactions.Item.RemoveAll(i => i.FundCode == "11277");`

Comment: thank you it worked,but how can I filter my items by fundcode and return AllTransactionsResponse

Comment: @EhsanAkbar can you give example

Comment: I want to filter my data on FundCode and finally my query returns a model with AllTransactionsResponse type

Comment: just return `allTransactions` after `allTransactions.Item.RemoveAll(i => i.FundCode == "11277");` ?